# How can I encode a NumPy array of object elements into ASCII?

Tags: python, numpy, ascii

Suppose, I have four lists of different data types. I also have a two-dimensional matrix. I want to merge them column-wise.

Say, in the following source code:

```
train_x_111 == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
train_y_111 == ['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef', 'defg', 'efgh', 'fghi', 'ghij', 'hijk', 'ijkl', 'jklm']
train_z_111 == [[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
 [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
 [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
 [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6],
 [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7],
 [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8],
 [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
 [ 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
 [0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1],
 [0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2]]
```

I want the following output in a text file:

```
1    a    abcd     0.0     0.1     0.2     0.3
2    b    bcde     0.1     0.2     0.3     0.4
3    c    cdef     0.2     0.3     0.4     0.5
4    d    defg     0.3     0.4     0.5     0.6
5    e    efgh     0.4     0.5     0.6     0.7
6    f    fghi     0.5     0.6     0.7     0.8
7    g    ghij     0.6     0.7     0.8     0.9
8    h    hijk     0.7     0.8     0.9     1.0
9    i    ijkl     0.8     0.9     1.0     1.1
0    j    jklm     0.9     1.0     1.1     1.2
```

**source_code.py**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_x_111, train_y_111, train_z_111 = load_data() # load_data() returns three TF tensors

    features_data_int_2d = np.array(train_x_111, dtype=int)
    sum_int_1d = np.sum(features_data_int_2d, axis=1)
    sum_int_1d = sum_int_1d.reshape(-1, 1)

    sum_data_1d_obj = sum_int_1d.astype(np.object_)
    features_data_2d_obj = np.array(train_x_111, dtype=np.object_)
    classes_data_1d_obj = np.array(train_y_111, dtype=np.object_)
    classes_data_1d_obj = classes_data_1d_obj.reshape(10,1)
    classes_string_1d_obj = np.array(train_z_111, dtype=np.object_)
    classes_string_1d_obj = classes_string_1d_obj.reshape(10, 1)

    sum_matrix = np.concatenate((sum_data_1d_obj, classes_data_1d_obj), axis=-1)
    sum_matrix = np.concatenate((sum_matrix, classes_string_1d_obj), axis=-1)
    sum_matrix = np.concatenate((sum_matrix, features_data_int_2d), axis=-1)

    sum_matrix = sum_matrix.encode('ascii')
    print(sum_matrix)
    np.savetxt("my_file.txt", sum_matrix, fmt='%s', delimiter='\t')
```

**Error output**

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe C:/Users/pc/source/repos/my_project/data_hashing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\source\repos\my_project\data_hashing.py", line 151, in <module>
    sum_matrix = sum_matrix.encode('ascii')
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'encode'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I encode a NumPy array of object elements into ASCII?

Comment: Does [this page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.io.html) have what you want?

Comment: @RandomDavis, No, it doesn't. You haven't understood the question.

Comment: Post something reproducible. I know nothing about your data.

Comment: The output format ought to be specified. TABs in the Markdown source is not sufficient (TABs render as space here; that is, they are ***not*** preserved in the output). E.g., are the numbers really to separated by ***one space*** and ***one TAB*** (***two*** whitespace characters)? There is also an exception for the separate between the first and the second column (only a TAB, no space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the following line

```
sum_matrix = sum_matrix.astype('U')
```

in place of

```
sum_matrix = sum_matrix.encode('ascii')
```

Comment: Given the information in the question, or lack thereof, this is unlikely to help future readers. Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

.encode('ascii') only works on strings, you should replace the problematic line with:

```
newArray = []
for i in range(len(sum_matrix)):
    newLine = []
    for j in range(len(sum_matrix[0])):
        newLine.append(str(sum_matrix[i][j]).encode('ascii'))
    newArray.append(newLine)
sum_matrix = np.array(newArray)
```

This basically goes through your array and encode each element the input it all back into an array. There might be a way to vectorize the encode function, but I don't know how to use this.